# Objective C: Take A Photo and Attach in EMail

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to make an app that uses the camera of the device to take a photo then attach it to email. I tried to code it but the image don't attach. What I am doing is after taking a photo it will be viewed first on a `UIImageView`then , clicking the "Done" button will save the image to sandbox and retrieve it for attachment.

Here's my code:
For saving the image...

```
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(attachingImage, 1);
jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"defectImg.jpg"];
[imgData writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
```

For Attachment...

```
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:jpgPath];
    NSData *myImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
    [tempMailCompose addAttachmentData:myImageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"defectImage.jpg"];
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[UIImage imageNamed:]` does not load arbitrary images. It can load images from your bundle (the images you added in Xcode), that's it.

Instead of `UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:jpgPath];`

You want to use `imageWithContentsOfFile:` to load an image from disk.

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:jpgPath];
```

Also:

You are creating a png image and attach it as a jpeg.

And it's not necessary to save the NSData to disk, just to load it a couple of seconds later. Pass the imgData reference to the mail composer.

Comment: thanks! I did pass the imagData to mail composer. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Also. You can compose a letter with html. So you decide where to put the picture.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [MFMailComposeViewController new];
mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
NSString *subject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ by %@", m_art.title, [m_art.author authorFullNameByReverse:NO]];
[mailController setSubject:subject];

NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body>Hi,<br>"];
body = [body stringByAppendingFormat:@"<img src='%@' width = '50%%' height = '50%%'><br>", [Utils urlAtArtPath:m_art.url]];
body = [body stringByAppendingFormat:@"More info here: <a href='%@'>%@</a></body></html>", m_art.url, m_art.url];

m_mail.enabled = NO;

[mailController setMessageBody:body isHTML:YES];
```

Comment: What are Utils and m_mail?